# //! [0] C++ - what is it?

Tags: c++, directive

what does `//! [0]` do in C++? I believe it's something that changes the language defaults, like turning off lazy evaluation or something, but I don't know exactly. Something with arrays?

Comment: it is a comment?

Comment: Looks like that's a comment.

Comment: It doesn't do anything special in standard C++.  It's just a comment.  Perhaps it's some proprietary extension for some compiler

Comment: No, it is not a comment, has blue, not green colour.

Comment: @CharlesSalvia Correction: It doesn't do anything in _any_ C++.

Comment: @user2420535, your syntax highlighter is confused

Comment: C++ does not use lazy evaluation.

Comment: IIRC this is one of the forms Doxygen collects. The basic one is /// but //! is an alternative.

Comment: @user2420535 It's blue because your editor is recognizing it as a doxygen comment

Comment: @user2420535: C++ does not place any meaning at all on the contents of comments, nor does it define what blue or green might mean in your editor. Your editor is highlighting it for reasons that have nothing to do with its meaning *as C++ code*.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Dead link.

Comment: Bah, it worked yesterday. I've deleted the comment now

Answer (score 39, accepted):

That's a comment of course. Still it has a special meaning for [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdsnippet):

> **\snippet  ( block_id )**
>
> Where the `\include` command can be used to include a complete file as source code, this command can be used to quote only a fragment of a source file.
>
> For example, the putting the following command in the documentation, references a snippet in file `example.cpp` residing in a subdirectory which should be pointed to by `EXAMPLE_PATH`.

```
\snippet snippets/example.cpp Adding a resource
```

> The text following the file name is the unique identifier for the snippet. This is used to delimit the quoted code in the relevant snippet file as shown in the following example that corresponds to the above \snippet command:

```
QImage image(64, 64, QImage::Format_RGB32);
image.fill(qRgb(255, 160, 128));
//! [Adding a resource]
document->addResource(QTextDocument::ImageResource,
    QUrl("mydata://image.png"), QVariant(image));
//! [Adding a resource]
...
```

> Note that the lines containing the block markers will not be included, so the output will be:

```
document->addResource(QTextDocument::ImageResource,
QUrl("mydata://image.png"), QVariant(image));
```

> Note also that the `[block_id]` markers should appear exactly twice in the source file.

Here `0` is the *block id*.

Answer (score 8):

It is a single-line comment...

Comment: Yeah, add dots so that your answer can actually be submitted.